# Shorthand for calling as function or using as string in python

Tags: python, built-in, shorthand

So I have a variable that I want to be a string or a function which returns a string from a given object instance.

Basically:

```
def evalstr(var, someob):
    if callable(var):
        return var(someob)
    else:
        return var
```

It seems like something that would have a builtin. Is there kind of clean shorthand/builtin function for this?

Comment: There is no builtin function to do this, there might be a shorter way but `shorter != better`. Your current function is clear and readable, and shows exactly what it is doing on first glance.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to change, but if you're just going for less wordy or more "elegant" code, change the else if to a ternary.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not shorthand, because it would not be a good idea. You *could* write the above with a `try`/`except TypeError` clause, but I still can't imagine a case where a function like that is useful (maybe you could enlighten us?). A docstring for this function would likely be longer than the function body, and from the name of the function alone one would hardly be able to induce what the function does. So I guess either the information here is just too little to be useful (and you should show us the whole use case), or (and that is my guess) you are on the wrong track with this.